# RICHTEX32.OCX problem

Tags: vb6, registration, ocx

I have a problem with a VB6 app causing a 50003 error whenever a form loads that uses RICHTEX32.OCX.

The problem does not occur on the development machine.  I tried copying and registering the development machine's copy of the OCX on the target machine, but this did not work.

What other things should be done to try to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try running reg-free COM at production environment with a copy of RICHTEX32.OCX from your dev machine.

Nowadays VB6 deployment can be 100% reg-free, oh joy! MS implemented it for .Net but VB6 devs are the winners.

Comment: Actually several MSDN articles say it was developed for VB6!  Sadly we never got a VB7 supporting it directly.  100% reg-free sounds nice but that's a bit of hyperbole since you can't use it for things like ActiveX EXEs.  Close enough to 100% to be very useful though.

Comment: I would also avoid using components taken from your running system for any deployment.  Use the copies from the redist packages, which you should unpack into a redist folder as alluded to in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830761

Comment: Agree on both points. We're using in-proc multi-threading, so no ActiveX EXEs here anymore. Reg-free COM supports inter-thread marshaling just fine.